# Clear Ember.TextField after submit

Tags: ember.js

I'm learning ember.js on a small example app and there is a final piece I can't get to work.

I have a list of "quips" (tweets) and there is a text input field that allows to create a new one. After I submit a new tweet, I want to clear the text input, to no avail. I basically copied the [todomvc example](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs) verbatim at this point and it works there (I even use the same ember.js and ember-data.js versions just to rule out this possibility).

Here is the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <h2>Latest Quips</h2>
    <div>
            {{view Ember.TextField id="new-quip" placeholder="Enter your Quip"
            valueBinding="newQuip" action="createQuip"}}
    </div>
```

The action in the appropriate controller:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  createQuip: function() {
    App.Quip.createRecord({
      text: this.get('newQuip'),
      user: 'ree'
    });
    this.set('newQuip', ''); // this row should clear the view
    this.get('store').commit();
  }
});
```

And the model for the sake of completeness:

```
App.Quip = DS.Model.extend({
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: 'App.QuipsAdapter'
});

App.Quip.FIXTURES = [
    { id: 1, user: 'ree', text: 'Which is the best JS MVC?' },
    { id: 2, user: 'baaz', text: '@ree Definitely Ember.js!' }
];

App.QuipsAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});
```

The app [runs here](http://reebalazs.github.com/quipper/src/index.html).

I would be really glad if someone could point at what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you,

Balint

Comment: I haven't used emberdata, the pure ember stuff looks reasonably right. I've run a basic test of your concept without persistence and it cleared the field as expected. one thing that looks slightly odd to me is that you commit the store after you have cleared out the field... but I don't see how that would cause your problem. (also, the this.get('store').commit() idiom isn't in the guide... but then a  lot of stuff isn't)

Comment: Yes, I wasted hours following code and advice found in the guide and in projects that turned out to have been written for Ember 0.9.x.  What finally seems to work is to follow the todomvc example since that's updated for 1.0.pre?. That works as long as my app stays no more complicated than the todolist app :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug related to jQuery 1.9.0 - try v1.8.x

Also, as I can recall, it's been fixed on master, so grabbing the latest Ember release may also solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, Gabor, downgrading to jQuery 1.8.3 in fact solved the problem.